# unable to detect theme changes in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am creating a Windows Phone application using default theme resources provided.

I am facing an issue with theme changes that when i change theme from light to dark and vice versa, the change is not immediately seen in my application. I am not using any custom colors.
But if i close my application and start again, theme changes are applied then.

Can somebody help me, to see if i am doing something wrong?
Any help will be highly appreciated
Thanx in advance

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344189/change-background-of-wp7-application-if-theme-is-altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

The theme settings are set when an application is first started.
It is not expected to respond to changes made at a system level while in a deactivated/tombstoned state.

In reality, I've only ever seen this noticed during testing. People don't change their themes and accent colors that often.

Comment: ya thats true, but this case can be taken as a valid test case. and i think must be considered if the application needs to be theme - aware

Comment: @Uday0119 if that's a valid test case for you you'll need to raise it against the framework which I'm guessing isn't a practical solution.